# Multithreaded storing into file

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have code

```
const int N = 100000000;
int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("result.txt", "w");
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        int res = f(i);
        fprintf (fp, "%d\t%d\n", i, res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here `f` averagely run for several milliseconds in single thread.

To make it faster I'd like to use multithreading.

1. What provides a way to get the next `i`? Or do I need to lock, get, add and unlock?
2. Should writing be proceeded in a separated thread to make things easier?
3. Do I need a temporary memory in case `f(7)` is worked out before `f(3)`?
4. If 3, is it likely that `f(3)` is not calculated for long time and the temporary memory is filled?

I'm currently using C++11, but requiring higher version of C++ may be acceptable

Comment: Can't you use a `std::vector` to store result (asynchronously)? then just dump vector (serially).

Comment: Multithread file access is very unlikely to be faster. Your bottleneck is at hard drive access, not at processor cycles. You could use C++ streams to save time on flushing (they use internal buffers before really accessing file) or Jarod's suggestion of storing data first instead of generating on the fly.

Comment: I doubt multithreading will be faster. First, you'll need to synchronize your access to your file since you print sequentially to it. Second, file I/O is almost certainly the bottleneck.

Comment: @Jarod42 That may cost too much memory. Or maybe do 100000 and store?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I don't think writing tens of integer cost millisecond

Comment: Why? First off, this is a text file, with "records" (lines) of different size. And a file pointer (or handle) has only one current position. You will need to create it (once) and open it multiple times. And due to the different size of the lines, it is impossible anyway. And no speed benefit, the data will have to be written by the same disk head or what. So...

Comment: Is `f` or `fprintf` the bottleneck?

Comment: 1. Why, oh why, do you store numbers as strings...?  and; 2. Consider using a temporary buffer to minimize disk access / system calls (i.e., use a 4Kb buffer and dumps it to disk whenever there's no more room for new data); 3. Threads aren't likely to solve your bottle-neck when writing to files.

Answer (score 0):

General rule how to improve performance:

1. Find way to measure performance (automated test)
2. Do profiling of existing code (find bottlenecks)
3. Understanding findings in point 2 and try to fix them (without mutilating)
4. Do a measurement from point `1.` and decide if change provided expected improvement.
5. go back to point 2 couple times
6. Only if steps 1 to 5 didn't help try use muti threading. Procedure is same as in points 2 - 5, but you have to think: can you split large task to couple smaller one? If yest do they need synchronization? Can you avoid it?

Now in your example just split result to 8 (or more) separate files and merge them at the end if you have to.

This can look like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <fstream>

std::vector<int> multi_f(int start, int stop)
{
    std::vector<int> r;
    r.reserve(stop - start);
    for (;start < stop; ++start) r.push_back(f(start));
    return r;
}


int main()
{
    const int N = 100000000;
    const int tasks = 100;
    const int sampleCount = N / tasks;

    std::vector<std::future<std::vector<int>>> allResults;
    for (int i=0; i < N; i += sampleCount) {
        allResults.push_back(std::async(&multi_f, i, i + sampleCount));
    }

    std::ofstream f{ "result.txt" }; // it is a myth that printf is faster
    int i = 0;
    for (auto& task : allResults)
    {
        for (auto r : task.get()) {
            f << i++ << '\t' << r << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We have enough independent tasks(1e8). Spliting result to files and then merge with another run?

Comment: probably `f(x)` is to small to separate it to single task. Synchronization would kill any gain. You have to group `f(x)` into larger group to see performance gain.

Comment: @l4m2 check answer update. Use if `std::future` is easier safer. Still your first move should be try optimize `f(x)`.

Comment: Looks like it creates 100 threads and store everything in RAM, totally bad idea it seems

Comment: no it doesn't. It creates 100 futures, which are processed by thread pool (which contains limited number of threads). The futures are queued for execution. Every time loops reaches `task.get()` it waits until results are ready. When `get` is called shared state is released. You can increase `tasks` to reduce memory consumption. Depending on how big thread poll is number of allocated vectors will change.

Comment: Also you can tweak code  and replace `std::vector<std::future<std::vector<int>>>` with a `std::queue<std::future<std::vector<int>>>` which will be filled to some limit. Code will be more complex but you will have more control over memory consumption.